# How to extract indices of non-zero elements from ND array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, graph, matlab-figure

I need to label edges of a directed graph with 4 different labels, so I store it in a N*N*4 array. (Let's stick with 4, which is my actual third dimension.) N is the number of nodes in the graph. i.e. for entry M(i,j,1), I would label an edge from node i to node j with the first kind of label. Here is a toy example to play with.

`M(2,1,1)=1` indicates I add label text 'first label' on the edge from node 2 to node 1. `M(3,2,2)=1` indicates I add label text 'second label' on the edge from node 3 to node 2. Each 'page' in the 3D array is one kind of label.

```
M(:,:,1)= 0 0 0      M(:,:,2)= 0 0 1         
          1 0 1                0 0 0
          0 0 0                0 1 0
```

But I don't know how to convert  N*N*4 array `M` into `s` and `t` in `labeledge(h,s,t,Labels)`. `s` is the indices of source nodes while `t` is the indices of target nodes.

Ideally, this is the plot:

```
s = [2 2 1 3];
t = [1 3 3 2];
G = digraph(s,t);
figure;
h = plot(G);
```

the key question is how I can get s1, t1, s2 and t2 from M like this:

```
labeledge(h,[2 2], [1 3], 'first label');
labeledge(h,[1 3], [3 2], 'second label');
```

[image]
FYI: `M(:,:,1)` and `M(:,:,2)` do not have the same non-zero entries.

Comment: Say it is 100, will you be writing 100 such lines `labeledge(h,[2 2], [1 3], 'first label');`? What's your plan on that?

Comment: @Sardar Thanks for your advice! Edited

Comment: Wait, do you also want to get adjacency matrix `adj` from `M`?

Comment: @SardarUsama No, I have got `adj` and `M` separately. I can plot the graph now, but I can't add 4 types of `labeledge`.

Comment: Wasn't my code giving you those edges? What exactly is the result in the form of numbers do you want?

Comment: @SardarUsama I also think it should, but somehow there is error saying: s and t must specify edges in the graph. Thus I was wondering if it's because the order of indices is different in `s{i}`, `t{i}` compared with the order in `adj`. // `adj` has all edge information but it contains 4 types of different edges which indicates relation between nodes in my case. So I want to distinguish them with labels (and better colors).

Comment: It has nothing to do with that! What is `nodeNameC.Var1` in your question? If you run my code and make digraph with `G=digraph(adj);`, it will run fine

Comment: node names whose orders are the same with the indices in `adj`. `nodeNameC` is a `table` in which there is a column named `Var1`, and `nodeNameC.Var1` is a cell

Comment: @SardarUsama Thanks! You can post your solution again and I'll accept it. I might make some other mistakes irrelevant to this part, which I'll fix later.

Comment: I rolled back the question to the version most relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some Background Insight:**

In your problem, the order of `s` and `t` is inter-linked i.e. shuffling of `s` does not matter if the elements of `t` are also shuffled in the same order. e.g;  if

```
s = [2 2 1 3];
t = [1 3 3 2];
%The combination of s and t given by you
```

The above will give the same result as that of the following:

```
s = [2 3 2 1];  
t = [1 2 3 3];
% replaced column 2 with column 3, column 3 with column 2, and column 4 with column 3
```

There are many such combinations.
The code I am going to show will give the following combination for the given `M`:

```
s = [2 2 3 1];    %named as snew in my code
t = [1 3 2 3];    %named as tnew in my code
%In this combination, column 3 and 4 are inter-changed (See the combination given by you)
```

---

**Code:**

```
for k=1:size(M,3)           %Looping depending on the third dimension
    [r,c]= find(M(:,:,k));  %Finding non-zero elements
    %Storing the values in a cell since the number of non-zero elements in each 
    %slice of M can be different 
    s{k}=r;     t{k}=c;    
end
```

The above code gives `s{1}=[2; 2]`, `s{2}=[3; 1]`,  `t{1}=[1; 3]`  and `t{2}=[2; 3]`.

Now you can find `s` and `t` as combined as given in your question by extracting them from the above code with:

```
snew=vertcat(s{:});   %Giving a different name to avoid confusion
tnew=vertcat(t{:});
```

Now you can make `digraph` using `snew` and `tnew` and label edges with `s{1}`, `s{2}`, `t{1}` and `t{2}`.

For labeling the edges, you can use the following loop:

```
for k=1:length(s)
    labeledge(h,s{k}, t{k}, ['label ',num2str(k)]);
end
```

This solves the issue of labeling if there are too many labels to make. Making the labels as `first`, `second` ,.... would be cumbersome and may be unnecessary.

---

**Output:**

With the above modifications, you get the following output:

[image: output]

Comment: I only used your first chunk of codes since I have an adjacency matrix with sorted indices already(i.e. [1 2 3 4 5]). i.e. I didn't use `vertcat` and only added `labeledge` after my original `plot(G)`. I'm wondering if this is okay since indices in `labeledge` is not the same as that in adjacency matrix.  Somehow your code does not work in my case and says: Error using
matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.GraphPlot/labeledge
s and t must specify edges in the graph.